# jQuery validate plugin TypeError: elem is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fluid form. I validate my form using the jQuery validate plugin. But on submit I get an error

> TypeError: elem is undefined

My code:

```
<f:form id="user_form">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><f:translate key="email" /></th><td></td>
    </tr>

    <f:for each="{users}" as="user">
      <tr>
            <td> <a class="editable" id="email" data-validation="email"  data-validation-error-msg="You did not enter a valid e-mail">{user.email} </a></td><td></td>
      </tr> 
    </f:for>

</table>
   </f:form>
```

jquery.js

```
$('#user_form').validate({
        form : '#user_form',
        modules : 'location, date, security, file',
        validateOnBlur : false,
        errorMessagePosition : 'top',
        scrollToTopOnError : false, 
        onModulesLoaded : function() {
          console.log("Load jquery validates");
        }
  });
```

The following script is included in my header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.23/jquery.form-validator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the submit handler ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH I have an xeditor.The validator excecutes on 'save' event of xeditor

Comment: Your a tag is in a loop, and has an id which is static, repeating id on an html page is invalid. This might not necessarily be the problem though. But still needs fixing.